# How can I change the attribute of parent class by dynamically referring to its static variables?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm reading new 'variable = value' pairs in a child class. The 'variable' is read as a string. The value varies, it can be and an integer, float, boolean etc. Reading multiple of such pairs is also possible. There are so many options for variables that doing things dynamically seems like the only feasible option.

The question is, how can i change these Parent class static variables without referring directly to the variable name. I do not want to change the data within the Child class instance, but rather in the Parent class directly.

Below is some code that obviously does not do what I want.

```py
class Parent:

    # the static variables that I want to change
    static_variable1 = "some_text"
    static_variable2 = 1.0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):

        # the data is not really defined in __init__ but for this example it doesn't matter 
        self.received_dictionary = {"static_variable1": "some_other_text",
                                    "static_variable2": 2.0}

    def change_parent_static_variables(self):

        # extract keys and values into lists
        variable_names = list(self.received_dictionary.keys())
        values = list(self.received_dictionary.values())

        # attempt to change Parent class static values
        for i in range(len(keys)):
            variable_name = keys[i]
            value = values[i]
            Parent.variable_name = value
```

Assume that in the real application, there are so many static variables in the parent class that it is not feasible to check for each variable with if-statements.

It is also OK if the Parent class has some sort of setter function that gets called by the Child class, and the setter function dynamically sets the static variables if the Parent class.

Comment: What language is this ? Python ? You should add a tag in the question it would be easier for the reviews for track your question and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for variable_name, value in self.received_dictionary.items():
    setattr(Person, variable_name, value)
```

or if you explicitly want to use the base class:

```
for variable_name, value in self.received_dictionary.items():
    setattr(self.__class__.__bases__[0], variable_name, value)
```